# Error while updating property 'nativeBackgroundAndroid' of a view managed by: RCTView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React native application crashes with the following error. I don't understand this error well. Any idea what is this error is about? I'm using React Native 0.31 and I'm getting this error in Android 4.4 in device Galaxy Core2

```
    com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'nativeBackgroundAndroid' of a view managed by: RCTView
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateViewProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:88)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackViewManagerSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:123)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:42)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.updateProperties(ViewManager.java:34)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:220)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:148)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.dispatchPendingNonBatchedOperations(UIViewOperationQueue.java:890)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:863)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedChoreographerFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedChoreographerFrameCallback.java:32)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:131)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:811)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateViewProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:77)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Attribute selectableItemBackgroundBorderless couldn't be found in the resource list
    at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactDrawableHelper.createDrawableFromJSDescription(ReactDrawableHelper.java:43)
    at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager.setNativeBackground(ReactViewManager.java:104)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: are you use `react-native-scrollable-tab-view`? if your are using `react-native-scrollable-tab-view`, must need to update v0.5.5 or above. Because of this error https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/issues/397

Comment: Yes, I'm use react-native-scrollable-tab-view. Let me check if the update fixes

Answer (score 1):

It's because nativeBackgroundAndroid isn't a valid property within the view.

I was able to recreate it by

```
<View style={styles.someStylesheet} nativeBackgroundAndroid={styles.someStylesheet}>
    //some view stuff
</View>
```

Comment: Okay, I see react-native has this piece of code,  not my code. Not sure how fix it.

Answer (score 0):

TouchableWithoutFeedback was causing the issue for me. I replaced it TochableOpacity with activeOpacity={0.9} as a workaround.

Other people have reported the same issue for TouchableNativeFeedback as well.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29414